# Transpôr lista de objetos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Como eu posso transpor as colunas de uma tabela como a da imagem abaixo
[image: tabela atual]

Para este formato:

```
Mercado | Semana 5 | Semana 6
FUT AUD | 0.9986   | 1.0035
FUT CAD | 1.0000   | 1.0062
FUT CHF | 1.0059   | 1.0158
```

Testei algumas implementações que encontrei em fóruns, mas usavam `var` para transpor, e como eu preciso mostrar os dados em um ListView e gravar em um arquivo CSV, preciso de um objeto pré-estabelecido.

O número de semanas varia (de acordo com o que o usuário escolher), podendo haver N semanas/colunas semana. Seria uma boa tentar transpor da lista para um DataTable?

Comment: para o arquivo csv, acho melhor manter nesse formato, se necessário depois pelo excel por exemplo você consegue exibi-los pivotando a tabela. Agora para o listview, veja se ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13148006/4713574

Comment: esse também: https://techbrij.com/pivot-c-array-datatable-convert-column-to-row-linq

Comment: Com o resultado pode variar, eu faria um DTO com o nome do mercado, número da semana e o valor e no próprio código agruparia por semana para gerar o CSV e a tabela. Para gerar o CSV existe uma [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) que pode te ajudar.

Comment: Qauntidade de colunas será fixa?

Comment: @jean somente a coluna 'Mercado' é fixa

Comment: Conseguiu algo com os links que coloquei ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Não utilizei especificamente os teus links, mas eles serviram como o norte da resolução (pivot table).

Answer (score 1):

**Resolução passo a passo:**

*Passo 1:*

Passei os dados da lista para uma `DataTable` pré-formatada (igual a da [imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JfXO.png) da pergunta).

```
var dtable = new DataTable();
            dtable.Columns.Add("Mercado", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dtable.Columns.Add("NSemana", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
            dtable.Columns.Add("Variacao", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
            foreach(var linha in relatorio.Futuros.Semanas)
            {
               foreach(var registro in linha.MercadoDaSemana)
                {
                    dtable.Rows.Add(new object[] { registro.Mercado.Simbolo, linha.SemanaDoAno, registro.TotalVariacaoMercado });
                }
            }
```

*Passo 2:*

Pivoteei a `DataTable` com o seguinte algoritmo:

```
 public static class FormatarDados
{

    public static DataTable ParaPivotTable(DataTable table, string columnX, string columnY, string columnZ, string nullValue, bool sumValues)
    {
        DataTable returnTable = new DataTable();

        if(columnX == string.Empty) { columnX = table.Columns[0].ColumnName; }

        returnTable.Columns.Add(columnY);

        List<string> columnXValues = new List<string>();
        foreach(DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {
            string columnXTemp = dr[columnX].ToString();
            if (!columnXValues.Contains(columnXTemp))
            {
                columnXValues.Add(columnXTemp);
                returnTable.Columns.Add(columnXTemp);
            }
        }

        if (columnY != string.Empty && columnZ != string.Empty)
        {
            List<string> columnYValues = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {
                if (!columnYValues.Contains(dr[columnY].ToString()))
                {
                    columnYValues.Add(dr[columnY].ToString());
                }
            }

            foreach (string columnYValue in columnYValues)
            {
                DataRow drReturn = returnTable.NewRow();
                drReturn[0] = columnYValue;
                DataRow[] rows = table.Select(columnY + "='" + columnYValue + "'");

                foreach (DataRow dr in rows)
                {
                    string rowColumnTitle = dr[columnX].ToString();

                    foreach (DataColumn dc in returnTable.Columns)
                    {
                        if (dc.ColumnName == rowColumnTitle)
                        {
                            if (sumValues)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    drReturn[rowColumnTitle] = Convert.ToDecimal(drReturn[rowColumnTitle]) + Convert.ToDecimal(dr[columnZ]);
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    drReturn[rowColumnTitle] = dr[columnZ];
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                drReturn[rowColumnTitle] = dr[columnZ];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                returnTable.Rows.Add(drReturn);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Não existem colunas para fazer a inversão");
        }

        if (nullValue != string.Empty)
        {
            foreach(DataRow dr in returnTable.Rows)
            {
                foreach(DataColumn dc in returnTable.Columns)
                {
                    if(dr[dc.ColumnName].ToString() == string.Empty)
                    {
                        dr[dc.ColumnName] = nullValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return returnTable;
    }
}
```

*Passo 3:*

Chamei a função `ParaPivotTable`:

```
  var tblRetorno = FormatarDados.ParaPivotTable(dtable, "NSemana", "Mercado", "Variacao", "-", false);
```

*Passo 4:* *

Gravei os dados da pivot table `tblRetorno` em um .csv:

```
CommonEngine.DataTableToCsv(tblRetorno, pathArquivo, ',');
```

*Utilizei o [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/).

O algoritmo do passo 2 foi segundo exemplo desse post [aqui](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22008/C-Pivot-Table).